# Nodejs post request to get oauth2 token for a service account

Tags: node.js, google-api, request, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to get an oauth2 token for my service account using nodejs. I'm following the documentation found here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#makingrequest

While there isn't a node example I've looked at the HTTP/Rest documentation to get a rough idea of what it expects when making a request for a token. However the response I'm getting back is:

Invalid JWT Signature.

As a general overview when computing the signature you take the base64url encoded value for the header and claim, hash it with sha256 and the private key from the google developer console, and then base64url encode that value.

So my header is:

```
    var header = {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
    var encodedHeader = base64url(new Buffer(header).toString('utf8'));
```

The documentation above even lists what this value will be after base64url encoding it:

```
    eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

And when I output my encodedHeader value:

```
    eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

Oh excellent it matches.So there shouldn't be a 64burl encoding issue for the other values. Next is the claim:

```
    var claim ={"aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send","iss":"*****censoredvalue*****gserviceaccount.com","exp":1505399833,"iat":1505396233}
```

It goes through the same process and is encoded.(Can't show for security reasons).

```
    var encodedClaim = base64url(new Buffer(claim).toString('utf8'));
```

For the moment I'm using third party sites to compute the signature for testing purposes but the input is encodedHeader.encodedClaim + Private Key(value being: -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY....) and using SHA256. I'll then take that output and b64url encode it.

I now have a JWT that is encodedHeader.encodedClaim.encodedSignature

```
    var encoded_jwt = encodedHeader + '.' + encodedClaim + '.' + encodedSignature;
```

I'll make a request to the token endpoint with the following:

```
    // Set the headers
    var headers = {
       'HTTP-Version': 'HTTP/1.1',
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    var bodyOptions = { 'grant_type': "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", assertion: encoded_jwt }

    // Configure the request
    var options = {
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        form: bodyOptions,
        json: true
     }

    // Start the request
   request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Print out the response body
            console.log(body)
        }
        else{
            context.log(error);
            context.log(response);
        }
    });
```

And this is where I get the response of an error saying that I have an invalid signature.

Any ideas as to why it's an invalid signature. I've also tried several signature generating sites to be sure it wasn't that one specific one but it's always the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To compute JWS, you can use [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) like the following :

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.pem', 'utf-8');

const signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
signer.update(data);
const signature = signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
```

where `data` is `encodedHeader + '.' + encodedClaim`

A complete example taken from [google-oauth-library](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/62e801c4b78594d7bb3f801a04e5adcc198df30e/ts/test/test.oauth2.ts) testcase :

```
"use strict";

const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('public.pem', 'utf-8');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.pem', 'utf-8');

const maxLifetimeSecs = 86400;
const now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
const expiry = now + (maxLifetimeSecs / 2);

const idToken = '{' +
    '"iss":"testissuer",' +
    '"aud":"testaudience",' +
    '"azp":"testauthorisedparty",' +
    '"email_verified":"true",' +
    '"id":"123456789",' +
    '"sub":"123456789",' +
    '"email":"test@test.com",' +
    '"iat":' + now + ',' +
    '"exp":' + expiry + '}';

const envelope = '{' +
    '"kid":"keyid",' +
    '"alg":"RS256"' +
    '}';

let data = new Buffer(envelope).toString('base64') + '.' +
    new Buffer(idToken).toString('base64');

const signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
signer.update(data);
const signature = signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64');

data += '.' + signature;

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet using the 'crypto' module worked well for me to generate a JWS using RSA-SHA256 signing algorithm and a private key. And finally using it to create the JWT required for an OAuth server.

```
import { createVerify, createSign } from 'crypto';

const privateKey = 'read from a file or key store';
const publicKey = 'read from a file or key store'; // only if signature verification is required

// header and claim - basis of the input that is going to be signed by the private key
const header = { alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT' };
const claim = {
  iss: 'MY_ISSUER',
  scope: '',
  aud: 'https://example.com/path/to/oAuth/token.json',
  iat: Date.now(),
  exp: Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000, // setting 1 hr
};

// create base64 of the header and claim
const base64Header = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header), 'utf8').toString(
  'base64'
);
const base64Claim = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(claim), 'utf8').toString(
  'base64'
);

// create the input from the encoded header and claim; 
// this is the input that is going to be signed by the secret key
const inputForSignature = `${base64Header}.${base64Claim}`;

// create the signing object using 'RSA-SHA256' algo,
// and add the input to it
const sign = createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update(inputForSignature, 'utf8');
sign.end();

// sign the input using your private key and get the signature in base64 format
const base64Signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');

// optionally, if you want to verify the signature using the public key
const verify = createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verify.write(inputForSignature);
verify.end();
if(verify.verify(publicKey, base64Signature, 'base64')) {
  console.log('signature verified');
} else {
  console.log('signature could not be verified');
}

// form the JWT by concatenating the above encoded parameters separated by dot (".") 
const JWT = `${base64Header}.${base64Claim}.${base64Signature}`;
console.log(JWT); // you are looking for
```